# How can I set the default value based on the submitted values?

Tags: drupal-7

The purpose of the page is to show a list of jobs. The form at the top lets you filter the results. Once the form is submitted I want to show the form again as well as the values that were put in. How would I go about this in drupal. The form code is below.

```
function ac_resume_job_list_form($form, &$form_state)
{

  $form['display_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'Display Options',
    '#attributes' => array("style" => "width:250px"),
  );

  $form['display_options']['limit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Limit',
    '#size' => 2,
    '#default_value' => 'the value of the submitted form',
  );

  $form['display_options']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Change Display',
  );


  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` in the form submit handler, and basically you'll have access to all of the submitted values in the `$form_state` variable in the form when it's rebuilt:

```
$default_limit = isset($form_state['values']['limit']) ? $form_state['values']['limit'] : 0; // Or whatever default limit you want to have.

$form['display_options']['limit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Limit',
  '#size' => 2,
  '#default_value' => $default_limit
);

// Brief example for the submit form
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```